# string isn't written out in function when called in if-statement.

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

The following code compile without any errors, but when I try to do 2 * 1 (or any other number that isn't 1) the string "Inte ok" from the ans function isn't written on the screen the program just quits. 
Why is that?

```
 //Test för att se om jag förstår funktioner

#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std; 

//Deklarerar variblar som jag ska använda
int a,b,x;
string s, ab;

//Skriver ut funktionen för att multiplicera
int multi(int a, int b) 
{
  x = a * b; 

  return x;
}

string ans()  
{
  using std::string; 

  string s = "Inte ok";

  ab = s;

  return ab; 
}

//Samlar in värde från användaren, skickar den till funtktionen "multi" som multiplicerar den, sedan skickar den tillbaks den till main via return. Main visar sedan
//resultatet för användaren

int main( void ) 
{

  using std::cout;
  using std::cin;
  using std::string; 

  cout << "Ange ett nummber som du vill multiplicera: \n\n"; 
  cin >> a;
  cout << "\n";
  cout << "Ange det andra nu: \n"; 
  cin >> b; 
  cout << "\n";


 if(a == 1) 
 {
  multi(a,b); 

  cout << "Svaret är: " << x << "\n";
 }
 else if (a =! 1)
 {
   ans;
   cout << "\n" << ab;
 }

  return 0; 

}
```

Best regards.

Comment: Why are you assigning to a global variable(ab) than returning it? Generally would pick one or the other (returning s)

Comment: As a side note: If you'd compiled with `-Wall` the compiler would have told you that there is probably something fishy in the line `else if (a =! 1)`. If memory serves me, gcc says something like *suggest parenthesis around assignment* (and as you didn't intend an assignment ...).

Answer (score 12):

`a =! 1` is not what you think it is. It's an assignment that assigns `!1` (which yields `0`) to `a`, so that condition will never be true. The unequality operator is `!=`, but there you just want `else`, with no additional condition. Also, to call a function `ans`, you need to do `ans()`:

```
if (a == 1) {
    multi(a, b);
    // ...
} else {
    ans();
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, a prime example of why to turn on compiler warnings.  As a sidenote, OP should use `endl` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: @Kevin: Not if they don't want to flush the stream every time they write to it.

Comment: @CatPlusPlus: Considering they're prompting for input they certainly should flush the buffer at least before every `cin`.

Comment: @Kevin: I think `cout` is required to flush automatically when `cin` begins a read.

Comment: @Kevin: Yes, `cin` and `cout` are tied, and you don't have to flush `cout` manually.